# Spitting on the ground

Tags: eretz-yisrael, derech-eretz-manners

In an essay on how seeing others sin makes the sin seem acceptable to you, I read that when 20th-century Rabbi Elya Lopian first came to Eretz Yisrael, he refrained from spitting on the ground (as was customary in the old country) because he deemed the ground too holy for that.  But when he repeatedly saw others do it, he relented and allowed himself to spit on the ground there.

I know spitting is allowed in general.  In the West, we don't spit on the ground anymore, anywhere.  In my native Egypt, they did it left and right in the street without anybody protesting.  The Shulchan Aruch even says:

> You may spit in [the synagogue] as long as you rub it out with your feet -- or, if there are reeds there such that, if you spit into them, it will not be visible.  [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Hayyim 151:7]

But is there a halacha that says one is not allowed to spit on the ground *in Eretz Yisrael*?

Comment: AFAIK no such halacha. So this was more of a *hanhagah* based on personal feeling. It sounds like Rav Lopian decided his hanhagah was too extreme and corrected course. So not a good example for the essay.

Comment: A yevama spits on the ground, presumably, in Eretz Yisroel as well.

Comment: @Chatzkel --  But that's in the Torah, and besides, I assume it's done inside a building, not outside on the bare floor.

Comment: How about using an outhouse in Israel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. Yishaq Zilberstein fielded the following question and addressed it with his responsum (Hashuke Hemed, p. 664):

> האם ראוי שלא לירוק על אדמת ארץ ישראל
>
> שאלה: שמעתי שהצדיקים רבי אליהו לאפיאן זצ"ל ורבי אריה לוין זצ"ל לא ירקו
> על אדמת אח ישראל מתוך חביבות קדושתה וכמו שרבי אבא היה מנשק כיפי דעכו
> ופרש"י מחמת חיבת הארץ וקדושתה שהיתה חביבה עליו ומחזר שלא יצא שם רע על
> הדרכים. כשספרתי דבר זה לגיסי הגאון הגדול רבי חיים קניבסקי שליט"א
> ושאלתיו האם זו הנהגה הראויה להיעשות העיר מדברי הגמרא בברכות (כד) שם
> נאמר: אני ראיתי את רבי שגיהק ופיהק ונתעטש ורק. ופרש"י שרק על גבי קרקע
> הרי שרבנו הקדוש רק על גבי הקרקע למרות שגר בארץ ישראל. ולכאורה יש מכאן
> קושיא על הנהגת הצדיקים?
>
> תשובה: גיסי הגאון הגדול רבי חיים שליט"א השיב שאין ראיה מהנהגת רבנו
> הקדוש מכיוון ששם היה מדובר באמצע התפילה כמבואר בגמרא שם ולכן לא רצה
> להפסיק ולהבליע את הרוק בבגדו אבל יתכן שאם לא היה זה באמצע התפילה היה
> מקפיד להבליע הרוק בבגדו או ללכת לצדדים כדי שלא לירוק על אדמת הקדש יש
> להוסיף שיש מקרים שיש מצוה לרוק על הארץ כמו במצות חליצה כמבואר בשולחן
> ערוך (אהע"ז סימן קס"ט סל"ח) ובודאי שאם החליצה בארץ ישראל יורקים על
> אדמת הקדש כי קיום מצוה לא נחשב לביזיון עוד מבואר בשולחן ערוך (או"ח ש"נ
> ס"ג) שאם רוקו נתלש בפיו ומוכן לזרקו יש מי שאומר שלא ילך בשבת ד' אמות
> ברשות הרבים עד שירוק והוסיף המשנה ברורה (סקי"ד) שהוא הדין שלא ילך אז
> מרשות לרשות עד שירוק והטעם בכל זה כיון דלמישדייה קאי הרוק נחשב למשאוי
> במקרה זה מותר אף לרוק על הארץ הקדושה כי בזה צורך לא להיכשל באיסור שבת

In short, he understands it to be generally improper, however there are exceptions such as in order to perform the miswa of halisa which requires spitting on the ground, or in order to avoid carrying between domains on Shabboth in the event one has raised up spit/phlegm within their mouth. In those scenarios it would not be considered disgracing the Land.

In Shu”t Eres Yisrael, no. 51 (p. 72), R. Mordekhai Sion records the answers of R. Shelomo Aviner and R. Avigdor Nebenzahl respectively to this question:

> תשובה הגר"ש אבינר השיב לי: ודאי זה מבזה את ארץ ישראל צריך לחבב את הארץ
> כמו שמובא בסוף גמרא כתובות קיב אב אודות האמוראים שחיבבו את הארץ גם לא
> צריך לרוק בכל מקום כי זה מגעיל אנשים אמנם אם זה למצווה כגון חליצה מותר
> כי אין זה ביזיון
>
> הגר"א נבנצל כתב לי: לא נאסר

R. Aviner maintains that spitting on the ground in the Land of Israel does not afford it the proper respect, except for when it is required for a miswah like halisah. He also adds that one shouldn't really be spitting anywhere because it disgusts people. R. Nebenzahl tersely answers that it is not prohibited.

R. Haim Kanievsky briefly addressed a related question concerning whether it is permitted to spit at the Western Wall (שו"ת ידון משה ח"כ עמ' קנא):

> שאלה: האם מותר לרוק ברחבת הכותל המערבי
>
> תשובת הגר"ח קניבסקי: בעלינו לשבח לנוהגים כן מותר אבל סתם כך אין ראוי

It is permitted to spit for those that have custom during the recitation of 'Alenu, otherwise it is improper.

Comment: The citation אהע"ז סימן קל"ט סל"ח should be siman קס״ט.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In [Berachot 54a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.54a.7?lang=bi&with=Sefer%20Mitzvot%20Gadol&lang2=en), a Mishnah declares one may not spit on the Temple mount. Further, in [Berachot 62b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.62b.20?lang=bi&with=Sefer%20Mitzvot%20Gadol&lang2=en), Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi says that even nowadays, after the Temple's destruction, one may not spit on the Temple Mount, for this is like spitting in God's eye.

There is a dispute among Amoraim in Berachot 62b about spitting in a synagogue (as noted in the question), whether we compare Temple Mount restrictions to it, based on whether we allow one to wear shoes vs. whether we allow a shortcut.

From the singling out of the Temple Mount and silence regarding the rest of Israel; and given that there is no prohibition, either of wearing sandals or of taking a shortcut in Israel, it appears rather evident that, like Rav Nebenzahl tersely answers, it is not prohibited.